# What does yarn.resourcemanager.am.max-attempts really mean?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I have a configuration entry in the yarn-site.xml as follows:

```
<property>
  <name>yarn.resourcemanager.am.max-attempts</name>
  <value>4</value>
</property>
```

I would ask what it really means, given the following two scenarios：

1. Say, I have an ApplicationMaster and it has a bug. When I submit the application to YARN, will it try to start Application Master 5 times and then fail the application(I assume the bug causes the AM can't be started)
2. Say， I have started a yarn application， and I kill the ApplicationMaster process manually, will the applicationMaster be automatically restarted?
   If so, I do `kill the application - application restarted` for another 4 times, will the AM not be restarted any more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say the AM is buggy and dies.  Or it has a memory leak which causes it to exceed it's container size and gets killed.  If it dies 4 times then the application's state is `FAILED`.

So to answer your question, 1 is true assuming you mean 4 instead of 5 and 2 is true.  If you want to understand this more, look at [TestAMRestart.java](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-yarn-project/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-server/hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager/src/test/java/org/apache/hadoop/yarn/server/resourcemanager/applicationsmanager/TestAMRestart.java).

Comment: Thanks @tk421 for the helpful answer!